# Set value of textbox and fire text changed event

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I'm currently working on an autofill userscript where I require three fields to be filled automatically, I can achieve this much but the site doesn't register the fact that I've changed the fields - presumably because I've used JS to fill them.

Here is my code

```
var one = document.getElementById("t-1").innerHTML;
var two = document.getElementById("t-2").innerHTML;
var three = document.getElementById("t-3").innerHTML;

document.getElementById("text-1").value = one;
document.getElementById("text-2").value = two;
document.getElementById("text-3").value = three;
```

Can anyone recommend how I can make the text event fire?
I'm aware that the site uses jQuery so I'd imagine that it's something to do with that.

EDIT:
I know the event isn't fired because there are three images of crosses which change green when the site registers the input as valid.

Code snippet I believe they use for detection:

```
$("input[type=text]").on("propertychange change keyup paste input",function(){validate($(this).attr('id'))});
```

Comment: Are you using the onchange event, or the onkey* events?

Comment: You should create a function to do what you want in the text event and call it from the event and call it when you change the text.

Comment: @major-mann I have updated the answer with what I believe to be the code snippet they use for detection.

Comment: @jbarker2160 how would one go about doing that? I'm not a JavaScript expert by any means, I only passed CodeAcademy's website making course on it :P

Comment: @charries96 Unfortunately this has been marked as duplicate (Personally I think that while the solution is a duplicate, the question is not.) Using the code on the linked duplicate, you should be able to manually trigger the event

Comment: @major-mann thankyou for your help anyway, I've got it working as you said using that code.

Comment: @charries96 Great stuff! glad to hear you came right